# Paperclip attachment saving with incorrect S3 URL about 50% of the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

### Update:

So this is definitely related to the :hash_data option, specifically the :updated_at segment. Somehow the files are being *saved* to the S3 bucket with a different :updated_at value than Paperclip uses to *read* the file. Could this be due to some race condition, considering that it occurs intermittently? As I mentioned below, this issue began after upgrading Paperclip to 4.2.1.

I will greatly appreciate any thoughts/tips you guys have on this. Thank you!

---

When uploading images via Paperclip to S3 bucket, it sometimes saves the files with a different filename than that returned by the attachment#url method. For example, an image is saved to

```
main_event_photos_46_47fd4f3c2fea17fbb7a0bd27c648911557f9e12b_main.png
```

However calling @event.main_event_photo.url(:main) returns

```
main_event_photos_46_15744de74a36207b672356b5ad4c6b30eb4ba85f_main.png
```

So as you can see, the :hash section of the interpolation does not match, and I have no way of finding the actual url besides opening the bucket in the S3 console. This issue seems to occur about half the time. Sometimes uploading the exact same file **does** save properly, and the url method accesses it correctly.

This issue began occurring after we upgraded Rails/Ruby/Paperclip. We're now using:

- Ruby 2.1.5
- Rails 4.2.0
- Paperclip 4.2.1

Note that on development, files always save correctly (local filesystem). I have scoured Stackoverflow and Google to no avail. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Model:

```
has_attached_file :main_event_photo, {
:styles        => {   :original => {:geometry => "1280x800#", :format => 'png'},
                      :main => {:geometry => "640x400#", :format => 'png'},
                      :thumb => {:geometry => "330x220#", :format => 'png'}
},
:convert_options => {:original    => '-quality 80',
                     :main    => '-quality 80',
                     :thumb    => '-quality 80'
},
:default_style => :main
}.merge!(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS) # this is defined in the config/environments

validates_attachment_content_type :main_event_photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/x-png', 'image/pjpeg']
validates_attachment_presence :main_event_photo
```

Form (basically):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event, :url => { :action => @event.id.nil? ? "create" : "update" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :main_event_photo %>
<% end %>
```

Note we have many models with Paperclip attachments, and the issue occurs on each.

Comment: Can you show us your Paperclip definition in the model, as well as the form code?

Comment: @dgilperez I added the info you requested, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this turned out to be the result of a bug. I upgraded Rails to `4.2.1.rc1` which was released last week, and the issue was resolved. If anyone wants more information, check out the thread on Github: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1772. It includes a workaround for those who can't upgrade Rails.